# How to send the post values while pagination links call in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, pagination

I would like to pass the post values while clicking the links in pagination..

I wrote the pagination even if ajax calls..BUT,I'm unable to send all the values through pagination..

And Finally I got `appends()->render();`

So there I send all my POST values by using `appends($_POST)->render();`

It shows the link as [`localhost/example.com/hotel/hotelresults?MY_POST_VALUES&page=2`](http://%60localhost/example.com/hotel/hotelresults?MY_POST_VALUES&page=2%60)

But,It seems to be an error like that

[image]

Here,I send the `search_city` with several values through my post action.

But I don't know why doesn't works for me..

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it..

Hopes it might be helpful for someone else..So I posted my answer here..

**Controller**

```
public function postHotelresults()
    {
    .
    .
    .
    $sqlCond = 'WHERE 1 '.$this->getAreaCondition($_POST['search_city']);
    .
    .
    $query = "SELECT `h`.*,".$countquery.",".$minquery." FROM `abserve_hotels` as `h`";

    $query1 = DB::select($query.$sqlCond);

    $perPage = 2;
    $currentPage = Input::get('page', 1) - 1;
    $pagedData = array_slice($query1, $currentPage * $perPage, $perPage);
    $query1 =  new Paginator($pagedData, count($query1), $perPage);
    $query1->setPath('hotelresults');
    .
    .
    return view('hotel.list', $this->data,compact('query1'));
    }

public function getHotelresults()
    {
            $this->postHotelresults();
    }
```

Here,When we click the links in the pagination it pass its all values to the get method..

So,as I already said I use `appends($_POST)->render();` in view But instead of this I gave it like `appends($_REQUEST)->render();`.

Since `$_REQUEST` is used to get both the POST and GET values

According to this my view is like

**View**

```
<?php 
if(!empty($query1)){
?>
@foreach($query1 as $aHotelRoom)

{{$aHotelRoom->hotel_id }}
{{$aHotelRoom->logo}}

@endforeach
<?php
echo $query1->apends($_REQUEST)->render();
}
```

And in the controller I use to call the post method inside the get Which leads to call the all the functionalities in get.

And an important thing is Routing in my

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('hotel/hotelresults', 'HotelController@postHotelresults');
```

I gave like this.

Thanks,